# Visual Studio 2013 sp1 update download issue

Tags: visual-studio-2013, updates, service-pack

I am trying for last two days to download VS 2013 SP 1 update. I succeed to download only "VS2013.1" (1,165kb) application and when trying to start it its only shows for milliseconds VS 2013 black update screen and close. I downloaded from external link and also through VS Notification.

Any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  found solution!   NOD ESET Smart Security was producing this issue. I disabled it for 10 min. and download started as usual.